# Filter the filtered array and render

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I filter the filtered array? So let's say that I filter the products by price. Assume the value of the input range slider (price) is less than a thousand dollars then it will return an array that is less than the said value which is a thousand dollars. Now, if I want to filter again using the brand or category filter buttons, so for example I chose the brand 'ikea' from the brand filters. How can I filter the returned array from the filtered price? Right now, when I filter the products by the price it can return an array but when I filter again by category/brand then it will return an array that is not coming from the filtered price array.

Here are my codes:

```
export const state = {
  products: [], //this is where I stored all the products coming from the API
  filters: {
    categories: [], //this is where I stored all the categories
    brands: [], //this is where I stored all the brand
    price: 0, //this is where I stored the max price from the array
  },
};
```

**@param value** - an integer value that comes from the input range slider

```
export const loadFilterPrice = function (value) {
  return state.products.filter(product => product.price <= value);
};
```

**@param type** - a string value 'brand' or 'category'
**@param value** - a string value of brands/categories,

```
export const loadFilterProductByType = function (type, value) {
  if (value === 'all') return state.products;

  return state.products.filter(product => product[type] === value);
};
```

Comment: There's another issue as well. If you wanted to filter by both `category` and `brand` - say need to show only `table` category from `ikea` brand - that will also not be possible with the current logic.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: You need to create a method that loops through all properties in `state.filters`, and then filters and returns a filtered state by using `loadFilterProductByType` each time it loops. Finally, run `loadFilterPrice()` after the initial loop in your created method.

Comment: Can you show it to me? @RickardElimää

Comment: @J.Wujeck It's basically what Nick Vu did, but sure ... I can post an answer of my own. It's slightly different in how I solved it, compared to Nick, but it's the same principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You filtered products but you haven't assigned a new variable/state for filtered products

You can add a `filteredProducts` variable here

```
export const state = {
  products: [], //this is where I stored all the products coming from the API
  filteredProducts: [] //this should be a clone of `products`
  filters: {
    categories: [], //this is where I stored all the categories
    brands: [], //this is where I stored all the brand
    price: 0, //this is where I stored the max price from the array
  },
};
```

Whenever you assign a value for `products` from an API call initially, you can assign `filteredProducts` value too

```
//`respondedProducts` is from API calls
state.products = [...respondedProducts]
state.filteredProducts = [...respondedProducts]
```

Here is how we use it

```
export const loadFilterPrice = function (value) {
  if(!value) return state.products; //return the original product list

  return state.filteredProducts.filter(product => product.price <= value);
};
```

```
state.filteredProducts = loadFilterPrice(1000) //need to update filtered products variable
```

Similarly, we can apply it to `loadFilterProductByType`

```
export const loadFilterProductByType = function (type, value) {
  if (value === 'all') return state.products; //return the original product list

  return state.filteredProducts.filter(product => product[type] === value);
};
```

```
state.filteredProducts = loadFilterProductByType('brand', 'ikea') //need to update filtered products variable
```

---

As for your case of multiple filters, I'd suggest that you should have another state called `state.filterValues`

```
export const state = {
  products: [], //this is where I stored all the products coming from the API
  filteredProducts: [] //this should be a clone of `products`
  filters: {
    categories: [], //this is where I stored all the categories
    brands: [], //this is where I stored all the brand
    price: 0, //this is where I stored the max price from the array
  },
  filterValues: {
     category: 'all',
     brand: 'all',
     price: 0, 
  }, initialize filter values mapping
};
```

You also need to refactor

```
const loadFilterProductByType = function (products, type, value) {
  if (value === 'all') return products; //return the original product list

  return products.filter(product => product[type] === value);
};

const loadFilterPrice = function (products, value) {
  if(!value) return products; //return the original product list

  return products.filter(product => product.price <= value);
};
```

After that, you can apply filters according to filter values

```
function filter(key, value) {
   //possible keys 'price', 'category', 'brand'
   state.filterValues[key] = value

   let filteredResult = [...state.products] //original list
   for(const [key,value] of Object.entries(state.filterValues)) {
     if(key === 'price') {
        filteredResult = loadFilterPrice(filteredResult, Number(value))
        continue
     }
     loadFilterProductByType(filteredResult, key, value)
   }
  
   //update the final result to `filteredProducts`
   state.filteredProducts = filteredResult
}
```

Here is how we use it

```
filter('price', 1000)
filter('category', 'something')
filter('brand', 'ikea')
//reset filter
filter('price', 0)
filter('category', 'all')
filter('brand', 'all')
```

Comment: I'm getting an error 'products is not defined'.

Comment: which line did you get it, @J.Wujeck?

Comment: This line: filteredProducts: [...products]

Comment: @J.Wujeck oh it's just an example of how I clone it, where you assign a value for `products`, you can assign that value to `filteredProducts` too. It can be from your API call.

Comment: @J.Wujeck by the way, I updated that part to make it less confusing, please let me know if you have further questions :D

Comment: Its working now but there's a problem when the input range value is 0 then I increase the input range value (move the slider to the right) it will not display the products. Why is that happening?

Comment: `if(!value) return state.products;` you need to make sure to set the original list to the filtered products when value is 0 @J.Wujeck

Comment: Thanks for this. But I need to show an error message when the value is 0 then when I increase the input range it will display the products.

Comment: Now it's working fine for you? @J.Wujeck

Comment: Yes but there's a problem.

Comment: Hmm I don't have a runnable code here, I'm not sure which problem you're facing @J.Wujeck

Comment: How to fix this one? @nick-vu When I click the category 'office', it will display the products but when I click again a category 'kitchen' it will not the display products. It should be display the products when I click another category.  Can you please view this? This is the link: https://cozystore.netlify.app/

Comment: If you have only single filter on that category, you can modify the code to check the original list `state.products.filter(product => product[type] === value);` @J.Wujeck

Comment: I did that. But when I choose a category 'office' for example, it will the display products by office category and when I choose 'ikea' brand, it should filter the result of array in category

Comment: I updated my answer for the sake of your requirement, you can check it out :D @J.Wujeck

Comment: Its working now but I noticed that if I filter the products by category first it will display no products. But if I filter the products by price it will display and filter again by category it also display. The only problem is when I filter the products by category or brand first it will display no products.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. The value of property price in filterValues should be the max price of products array. So therefore the filter is working fine now. Thanks so much! @NickVu

Comment: Glad to hear that!~ :D

Answer (score 1):

This solution specifically attempts to answer below point:

> What should I do?

There are several ways to go about this. The optimal ways may be to use useMemo, useCallback, etc.

The below is just one way that it may be done, which relies only on `useState` and `useEffect`.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Thingy = ({initState, ...props}) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(
    [
      ...initState.products.map(
        x => ({...x, filtered: false})
      )
    ]
  );
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
    categories: "", brands: "", price: 0 // Number.MAX_VALUE
  });
  const [showFilters, setShowFilters] = useState(false);
  const [filterPrice, setFilterPrice] = useState(0);
  const renderFilterFor = col => (
    <div>
      <label> {col} </label>
      <select
        name={col}
        onChange={e => {
          const v = e.target.value;
          setFilters(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            [col]: v !== 'None' ? v : ""
          }));
        }}
      >
        {
          [
            'None', ...new Set(products.map(ob => ob[col]))
          ].map(cat => (
            <option value={cat}>{cat}</option>
          ))
        }
      </select>
    </div>
  );
  const applyFilter = pr => (
    Object.entries(filters)
    .filter(([k, v]) => ((k === 'price' && v > 0) || v.length > 0))
    .every(([k, v]) => ((k === 'price' && pr[k] <= v) || pr[k] === v))
  );
  useEffect(
    () => setProducts(
      prev => prev.map(
        p => ({
          ...p,
          filtered: applyFilter(p)
        })
      )
    ),
    [filters]
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => setShowFilters(prev => !prev)}
      >
        {showFilters ? 'Hide' : 'Show'} Filters
      </button>
      {
        showFilters && (
          <div class="filtersLine">
            <div>{renderFilterFor("categories")}</div>
            <div>{renderFilterFor("brands")}</div>
            <label for="priceInp">Enter price: </label>
            <input
              type="number" value={filterPrice} min={0}
              onChange={e => {
                const v = e.target.value;
                setFilterPrice(v);
                setFilters(prev => ({
                  ...prev,
                  price: +v
                }));
              }}
            />
          </div>
        )
      }
      {
        products.filter(({filtered}) => filtered).map(
          ({productId, productName, categories, brands, price}) => (
            <div class="singleProduct" key={productId}>
              {productName}
              <b>Category: </b>{categories}
              <b>Brand: </b>{brands}
              <b>Price: </b>{price}
            </div>
          )
        )
      }
    </div>
  );
};

const initState = {
  products: [...Array(15).keys()].map(i => ({
    productId: i+1,
    productName: `Product - ${i+1}`,
    categories: `Category - ${i % 3 +1}`,
    brands: `Brand - ${i % 4 +1}`,
    price: Math.floor(Math.random() * ((i+1) * 5))
  }))
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    DEMO
    <Thingy initState={initState}/>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("rd")
);
```

```css
.singleProduct {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 85%;
}
.singleProduct > *{
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.filtersLine {
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 85%;
}
.filtersLine > label { margin: 10px; }
```

```html
<div id="rd" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I'm not using js framework. I'm just using vanilla js.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would add all filters to an array and loop through that array, calling `loadFilterPrice` and `loadFilterProductByType` respectively.
2. I wanted to give the filters more structure that is easier to maintain, so I added a ProductFilter class.
3. I populated `state` with fifteen items with randomized `prices`.

This is an AND filter, so if you add (for example) two categories, `filterBy` will return an empty array.

I also assumed that you're using ES6.

```js
let productsFilterArr = [];

class ProductsFilter {  // 2
  constructor(type, value) {
    this.type = type;
    this.value = value;
  }
}

const filterBy = function (productsFilterArr, state) { // 1
  let filteredState = {...state} // Creates new copy

  for (const productFilter of productsFilterArr) {
    if (productFilter.type == 'price') {
      filteredState.products = loadFilterPrice(productFilter.value, filteredState.products);
    } else {
      filteredState.products = loadFilterProductByType(productFilter, filteredState.products);
    }
  }

  return filteredState;
}

/* COPIED CODE from sN00b */
var state = {  // 3
  products: [...Array(15).keys()].map(i => ({
    productId: i+1,
    productName: `Product - ${i+1}`,
    categories: `Category - ${i % 3 +1}`,
    brands: `Brand - ${i % 4 +1}`,
    price: Math.floor(Math.random() * ((i+1) * 5))
  }))
};
/* END: COPIED CODE */

const loadFilterPrice = function (value, products) {
  return products.filter(product => product.price <= value)
};

const loadFilterProductByType = function (productFilter, products) {
  return products.filter(product => product[productFilter.type] === productFilter.value);
};

/* JUST FOR SHOWCASING */

let filteredStates = {};

productsFilterArr = [new ProductsFilter('brands', 'Brand - 2'), new ProductsFilter('price', 10)];
filteredStates = filterBy(productsFilterArr, state);
console.log({productsFilterArr}, filteredStates);
console.log('-----------------------');

productsFilterArr = [new ProductsFilter('categories', 'Category - 1')];
filteredStates = filterBy(productsFilterArr, state);
console.log({productsFilterArr}, filteredStates)
console.log('-----------------------');
```